# format on save(prettier) doesn't work VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier-vscode

I have prettier installed. I can format the code by right-clicking the file and clicking the "format document", but I can't use Ctrl + S to format the code. I also set prettier as the default formatter.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I encountered this problem on certain types of files where a second possible formatter was found, for example react files in an create-react-app project. Setting prettier as default formatter for this type of file helped. So hence my question: do you have this problem on all files or just a specific type of file?

Comment: I just solved my problem. I checked the shortcuts, my ctrl+s was also bound with the "save without formatting". I removed the keybinding and then it works!!!